# MapMyFitness API - can't get OAuth2 working in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, oauth-2.0, mapmyfitness

All,

I'm attempting to use MapMyFitness' API and OAuth2.

Here's the stripped down code I'm using (similar to code I've used successfully to connect with Strava's and RunKeeper's API):

```
$mapMyRun_authorization_code = "*****";
$client_id = "*********";
$client_secret = "*************";

$url="https://oauth2-api.mapmyapi.com/v7.0/oauth2/access_token/";

$postfields = array(
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "client_id" => $client_id,
    "client_secret" => $client_secret,
    "code" => $mapMyRun_authorization_code
);

$headers = array('Api-Key: ' . $client_id);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$json = curl_exec ($ch);
$responsecode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I run this - `$json` is empty, and `$responsecode` is 400, not 200.

I'm obviously doing something wrong with my request, but I have no idea what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks to help from the MapMyRun team, here's the answer:

```
$mapMyRun_authorization_code = "*****";
$client_id = "*********";
$client_secret = "*************";

$url="https://oauth2-api.mapmyapi.com/v7.0/oauth2/access_token/";

$postfields = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" . $mapMyRun_authorization_code . "&client_id=". $client_id . "&client_secret=" . $client_secret;

$headers = array('Api-Key: ' . $client_id);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$json = curl_exec ($ch);
$responsecode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

The important changes - `$postfields` **cannot** be an array, and you should **not include** `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else...

Comment: {"error": "invalid_grant"}  getting this error plz help its urgent.